# How does the lightsensor values work? Lightsensorvalue into Percentage

Tags: mobile-robot, control, sensors, webots

In Webots: I try to build a [Braitenberg vehicle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braitenberg_vehicle) so that when it receives light information through the ligh sensors it drives either away or towards the light. I used an ePuck and tried to just connect the light sensors 0 and 7 to the left and right wheel. I placed a little light bulb with white light in front of it and disabled the scene lighting, so the light bulb is the only light source. The values from the light sensor readouts are always around 4100.

Now to my question: What is the maximum number the light sensor can measure? So I can connect the wheels to the sensor input and say it's fully exited, drive with max speed. When it is less excited, drive with less speed. What is the formula to convert light sensor values to percentage?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, Maximilian Klein. You're mentioning devices, but no frameworks, software, part numbers, etc. Saying something like `I placed a little light bulb with white light in front of it and disabled the scene lighting` makes it seem like you're in simulation - what simulator? You you mention the `light sensor readouts` - what light sensor? Can you link us to any documentation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.